# Show user-defined VHDL attribute during synthesis

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am working on a design (VHDL-2002) where user-defined attributes are attached to different design units. The attribute values may be passed through the design hierarchy.
Is there a (common) way to list the values of these attributes at synthesis time? Something like VHDL's `report` statement, but to be evaluated during synthesis...
My problem is with regard to design analysis, changes to the code, e.g. switching to generics instead of attributes, are undesired.
At the moment Xilinx XST 14.4 is used for synthesis, but I'm open to alternatives.
I'm asking since XST *does* report the attribute "Detected unknown constraint/property custom_attr", but unfortunately not its value.

Comment: Some synthesis tools (Xilinx XST) do evaluate "Assert" provided the asserted condition is static. I use this to check consistency of generics with internal assumptions but you can report on attributes too. Depending on its type, the `'image` attribute ought to work (but I can't say I've tried it)

Comment: You should update ISE to 14.7, because  Xilinx fixed and added some useful features since 14.4. If you plan to migrate to Vivado don't reley on ISE features - Vivado supports just a sub-subset of VHDL. ..

Comment: @Brian: That did it! Added `assert FALSE report "yadda" severity note;` in an entity body and the XST synthesis report now shows the report string as expected on a separate line right after elaborating the respective entity: "Note: yadda". A plain `report "yadda";` instead of the assert statement does not work.

Comment: @damage it depends where you use `assert` and `report`. E.g. you can not use `report` in an `architecture` on the other hand `asserts` are not supported in functions by every tool, but `report` works here. The reporting feature (either `assert` or `report`) is very tool specific. Xilinx Vivado had an `assert` statement until I reported [several bugs](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Vivado-Synth-Bug-in-handling-physical-types/m-p/557049). They removed the feature instead of fixing the bugs!

Comment: @Paebbels: I can remember at least one occasion where I used `report` within architectures (RTL code) to create log files during simulation. At synthesis time all `report` statements were suppressed by setting a generic to false, however. A disputable practice, but it did the job (must have been Xilinx ISE/XST 12.X). The bug report you linked is interesting as well; made me remember the Xilinx marketing guys telling me that everything will get better with Vivado :-/

Comment: @damage After my comment here, I searched for the xSim user guide (UG900) and found that xSim (Vivado simulator) supports only VHDL-93 whereas Vivado claims to partially support VHDL-2008. So you can write new code but you can't simulate it ... The problem with the physical types also shows that even VHDL-87 is not supported yet :).